# Accidental hickeys: How long do hickeys last? How to prevent the development of them next time?

Tags: lasting-effects-duration, neck, bruising-bruise, lips

I accidentally gave my long-term boyfriend of 4 years several hickeys on his neck this weekend. We make out all the time, and I've never given him hickeys before  (never desired or thought about giving him hickeys -- or even knew how), so I'm not sure how I gave him not just one, but several on his neck this weekend. I didn't seem to do anything different.

How long do hickeys last? What are good ways to promote the healing process?

Since I'm not sure how I managed to give him hickeys since I made out with him as I normally do, how do I prevent future hickeys -- he's pretty embarrassed about it. (Or I am... because everyone knows I'm his girlfriend).

Comment: Ice on it tends to help it go down faster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not a dermatologist, but hickeys are cutaneous very small bleedings when tiny blood vessels in the dermis, known as capillaries, get broken. They begin to bleed in to the small spaces below the epidermis called interstitial space. The best method to heal this bleedings is just to wait. Maybe cold application could help ... but the blood must be resorbed by body cells and it takes time.

So its not dangerous at all ... just wait :)

I hope that helps.